# Swaping elements doubly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I implement selecting sort and I need to swap elements.
I have doubly linked list with previous and next links.
And link to the first and last element in List
I always need to swap some node `b` with first node `toStartFrom`

```
public void Swap(Node toStartFrom, Node b) {
        Boolean NextToEachOther = (toStartFrom.next == b);
        toStartFrom.next = b.next;
        b.previous = toStartFrom.previous;
        if (NextToEachOther) {
            toStartFrom.previous = b;
            b.next = toStartFrom;
        } else {
            toStartFrom.previous = b.previous;
            b.next = toStartFrom.next;
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        Node current = first;
        while (current != null) {
            ...printing...
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work.
No errors just doesn't sort in right order.
And not diplays any elements after sort after `toStartFrom` node.

Comment: What did you observe when you stepped through your code in a debugger on a simple data-set?

Comment: Also, for a doubly linked-list where one of the elements is guaranteed to be the head, you will need to update 6 references.  Draw a picture to see why.

Comment: In debuging it's Ok they are swaped in debuging maybe I have a problem with displaying.

Comment: You mean it works properly when you run it in the debugger, but not when you run it for real?  Or do you mean that it just doesn't crash?

Comment: doesn't crash and all links are swapped between them

Comment: Like I said, you aren't updating enough links (references).  You're only updating 4, but you need to update 6 (`a.next.prev`, `a.next`, `b.prev.next`, `b.next.prev`, `b.prev`, `b.next`).

Comment: Why?  If it's just an arbitrary node in the list, then `b.next` is a reference to its neighbour, which will exist (in general).  Of course, you will need to handle the special case when `b` is at the end of the list, to avoid the exception...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also update the nodes that are next to the 2 being swapped

For instance, consider this list:

first -> a -> b -> c

If you wish to swap first and b then you must also update a's and c's next and prev references.

Edit: This code should be placed before your code that does the swap and right after the Boolean declaration

Edit2: Also, if you have refences to the head/tail of the list, you need to update those too.  I don't see that you referenced a head or tail anywhere in your code though.

```
if(toStartFrom.prev != null)
{
   toStartFrom.prev.next = b;
}
if(toStartFrom.next != b) // Equivalent to NextToEachOther
{
   toStartFrom.next.prev = b;
}
if(b.next != null)
{
   b.next.prev = toStartFrom;
}
if(b.prev != toStartFrom)  // Equivalent to NextToEachOther
{
   b.prev.next = toStartFrom
}
```

Comment: It's right, I need to change 6 links in general case, but my sort it doesn't work even with two elements.

Comment: did you also consider my edit2?  You have to update the head/tail references if you are tracking them (and why would you not be?)

Comment: @Nikita: What? I guess I don't fully understand you.  your code is definitely not complete. you MUST also change the surrounding nodes references and you clearly aren't.  you will potentially need to change up to 8 references, not 6

Comment: I get it. Six links in elements and two(head/tail) in list.

Comment: No. the head/tail references are in addendum to the 8 links that may have to be changed.  EDIT: notice that my code is changing 4 links.  Your code is changing 2 links outside the if/else block and 2 more links in the if/else block.  2 + 2 + 4 = 8.  That is 8 links (excluding head/tail references) that may have to be changed).  I say may because you will see my code I suggested is all wrapped in if() statements that may not need to be executed